# OData getting zero values in .net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, odata

I am developing a .net application using OData. When I call OData service from my application, I am getting zero values, but when I check same odata service in Browser, I am not getting zero values.  Please refer following screen shots.

**.net application output**

[image: .net application value]

**Browser output**

[image]

**Code**

```
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri(@"http:/service_url/sales_and_delivery.xsodata");

        SalesData.sales_and_delivery dataContext = new SalesData.sales_and_delivery(serviceUri);

        var query = (from d in dataContext.SalesOrderandDelivery
                     select d).ToList();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
               /// 
        }
```

What could be the possible reason?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your C# code for fetching and processing the odata service response

Comment: @MohsinMehmood. I have update the question. You can check

Comment: @stay_hungry did you use ServiceReference or WebReference ?

Comment: @WildanMuhlis. I used Service Reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous project, there is strange behavior while adding web service using `Add Service Reference`.

My Childs object doesn't load.

I then try to change the method to the predecessor method using `Add Web Reference` and child object loaded.

You could try to use `Add Web Reference`. Here is how to add web reference in the newer visual studio:
https://forums.asp.net/post/5660283.aspx

Also, make sure you map data type between web service and C# object correctly `Edm.Decimal` >> `Decimal`.

Comment: I have already tried to add as web service. But when i go to add as web service, I got a message "0 service found"